# How to return a parameter on the basis on another parameter in list of object

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have the following `InventoryItem` class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class InventoryItem {
    private String name;
    private int amount;
    // other properties, getters, etc.
}
```

And I have an `Inventory` object that contains a `List` of `InventoryItem`s.

I want to obtain the amount of the item where the name is equal to the given name.

I am trying to use streams for that purpose:

```
inventoryItems.stream().filter(item -> item.getName().equals(name));
```

But it is returning the whole item, I only want the `amount`. How can I do that?
I am new to java so do not have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter operation is an intermediate operation. We need one of terminal operation to get the result. Below are couple of ways to get the Amount

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class InventoryItem {
    String name;
    float amount;

    public InventoryItem(String name, float amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
public class ItemAmount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = Arrays.asList(new InventoryItem("A", 100f), new InventoryItem("B", 50f));

        //method-1
       float amount = inventoryItems.stream().filter(item -> item.getName().equals("B")).findFirst().get().getAmount();
       System.out.println("Amount of B item is: " + amount);

       //method-2
       List<InventoryItem> matchList = inventoryItems.stream().filter(item -> item.getName().equals("B")).collect(Collectors.toList());
       matchList.forEach(i -> System.out.println("Item: " + i.getName() + ", Amount: " + i.getAmount()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using JDK 14:**

I have implemented the below code using **records** instead of creating POJO's.

***Note (As a suggestion):*** As I can see in your given code, you are using ***some annotations***(`@AllArgsConstructor @Getter,..`) for auto creation of constructors, getters and setters, so for that boiler-plate code, ***records** seems to be a good option which is available from **java 14 onwards**.*

> **Records in java :** As of JDK 14, we can replace our data classes with records. Records are **immutable classes** that require only the type and name of fields. We do not need to create constructor, getters, setters, override toString() methods, override hashcode and equals methods.([records javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html))

***Please find the code below:***

```
public class Test {
        
          public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            String nameToFind = "item1";
            int amount = 0;
        
            record InventoryItem(String name,int amount){}
        
            Optional<Integer> optional = List.of(new InventoryItem("item1",100),
                    new InventoryItem("item2",200),
                    new InventoryItem("item3",300))
                    .stream().filter(x -> x.name().equals(nameToFind)).map(InventoryItem::amount).findFirst();
            
            if(optional.isPresent()){
              amount = optional.get();
            }
        
            System.out.println(amount);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the map() function, append it after the filter.

```
Optional<int> result = inventoryItems.stream().filter(item -> item.getName().equals(name)).map(item -> item.getAmount()).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are to issues:

- Your stream lacks a *terminal operation* which is needed to obtain the result of the stream execution.
- To `amount` from an `InventoryItem` you need to apply [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) operation.

That's how you can generate a list of amounts that correspond to the items having the given name:

```
public List<Integer> getAmountsByName(List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems,
                                             String name) {
    return inventoryItems.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.getName().equals(name))
        .map(InventoryItem::getAmount)
        .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
}
```

In case if names of items are expected to be unique, then you can apply `findFirst()` as a *terminal operation*, which returns an `Optional` as a result (because resulting value might not be present).

There are many possibilities how you can dial the `Optional`, for instance you can use `orElse()` to provide the *default value*, or `orElseThrow()` to throw an exception if a result was not found (sometimes it makes sense to return an `Optional`, and deal with it in the calling method).

That's how it might look like:

```
public int getAmountByName(List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems,
                           String name) {
        
    return inventoryItems.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.getName().equals(name))
        .map(InventoryItem::getAmount)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(-1); // in case if an item with the target name isn't present return zero
        //    .orElseThrow(); // alternatively you can throw an exception depending on your needs
}
```